# Select unique record if does not belong to group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to filter the table in such way that if the
City shares the same code should not get selected
Please advise how to achieve this.

| Code | City |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | MYS |
| 3 | NYR |
| 3 | STA |
| 4 | MYS |
| 4 | MYS |
| 5 | MYS |

Expecting Result

| Code | City |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | MYS |
| 5 | MYS |

Comment: use `GROUP BY` and `COUNT (  DISTINCT ) `

Comment: I have edited to title. Please avoid using all capital case. It is seems like shouting and consider rude

Comment: @Squirrel
 if I select distinct I will select the first row too

Comment: Not `select distinct` but use `COUNT ( DISTINCT ) ` together with `GROUP BY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL server using an `apply operator` allows for an efficient form of correlated subquery that can also be referenced in the where clause. Here we can count the distinct number of city values per code, and if this is 1 then output just those rows plus use `select distinct` to remove any duplicate result rows:

```
with a as (
    select 3 as code, 'MYS' as City
    union all
    select 3, 'NYR'
    union all
    select 3, 'STA'
    union all
    select 4, 'MYS'
    union all
    select 4, 'MYS'
    union all
    select 5, 'MYS'
    )
select distinct
     a.code
   , a.city
from a
cross apply (
       select count(distinct c.city)
       from a as c
       where a.code = c.code
       ) as ia (c_count)
where ia.c_count = 1
```

**result**

```
+------+------+
| code | city |
+------+------+
|    4 | MYS  |
|    5 | MYS  |
+------+------+
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b7c093d5dbe8eb615624b71d3e4f898a)*

Answer (score 0):

Can you try if this is what you want

```
with a as (
    select 3 as code, 'MYS' as City
    union all
    select 3, 'NYR'
    union all
    select 3, 'STA'
    union all
    select 4, 'MYS'
    union all
    select 4, 'MYS'
    union all
    select 5, 'MYS'
)
select *
from (
    select distinct code, city
    from a
) b
group by code
having count(*) = 1;
```

This was for Mariadb, but the logic is `distinct`, `count(*)` and `group by`. This is one way to do it

For SQL Server try this

```
Select distinct * from a where code in (select code
from (
select distinct code, city
from a
) b
 group by code
having count(*) = 1);
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=81579513f13e2bed8808fffe9813ec60)

Comment: You shouldn't need `distinct` if you use `group by`.

Comment: I don't think `select * from . ..  group by code` will work with `MySQL`. Anyway OP is using `SQL Server`

Comment: You meant "I think" ? because the answer is a mysql code where "select * from . ..  group by code" works

Comment: Distinct and group by are needed as they on different levels

Comment: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=33858b4d899e83b4609346bea40c9496)

Comment: Agreed its not going to work there in mysql, correction this is mariadb code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `group by Code` and `count(distinct City) = 1`. There is only one unique `City` in the result you may use `min` or `max` to display it

```
select Code, min(City) as City
from   yourtable
group by Code
having count(distinct City) = 1
```